# How to specify the precision/scale JDBC metadata of Oracle numbers?

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc

I need to force the precision and scale of a result column, to do custom formatting on currency values (I'm assuming every NUMBER(*,2) is a currency value).
Consider the following query:

```
select cast(1234.56 as NUMBER(6,2)) from dual;
```

It does the expected rounding if necessary, but the result metadata describes a Number field with unspecified precision and scale:

```
System.out.println( rs.getMetaData().getScale(1) ); // prints 0;
```

I believe something strange is happening on the JDBC side, because the following script does return a NUMBER(6,2) as expected:

```
drop table temp;
create table temp as (
select cast(1234.56 as NUMBER(6,2)) x from dual
);
select * from temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be

```
System.out.println( rs.getMetaData().getScale(1));  //For the first column
System.out.println( rs.getMetaData().getScale(2));  //For the second column
```

and so on.

Your code

```
System.out.println( rs.getMetaData().getScale(0) ); //0th Column??
```

Quote from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getPrecision%28int%29) link-

> **`getPrecision`**

```
public int getPrecision(int column)
                  throws SQLException
```

> Get the designated column's number of decimal digits.
>
> **Parameters**: **column** - the first column is 1,
> the second is 2, ...
>
> **Returns**: precision
>
> **Throws**: SQLException - if a
> database access error occurs